# Is "push a button" correct English? (as opposed to "press a button")

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, differences, collocation

My intuitive understanding of the English language (I am German) would correlate with the following quotation:

> The word "press" means to exert force on an object, but no motion of the object is implied.
>
> The word "push" also means to exert force on an object, but there is an implied sense of movement of the object being pushed.

([Source](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-push-and-press/answer/Frank-Dauenhauer) from an online forum)

Therefore, "press a button" is what I consider correct English if the intention expressed is that, e.g., a human hand is lowered onto a button in order to trigger a certain mechanism.

Meanwhile, "push a button" is what I would understand as a button sitting on top of a table when a cat enters the scene and decides to shove it off the table for its own amusement.

An associate corrected me today, stating it would in fact be "push a button" or else the song "Push the Button" would be grammatically incorrect. While I do not take the *Sugababes* [sic!] as the standard by which I measure correct speach, it made me wonder; is there any rule that makes one of these two options incorrect or are the both of us free to anarchically make use of any of these two choices?

Comment: On average, all Anglophones are more likely to ***press** a button* rather than ***push*** it, but this preference is [stronger in BrE than AmE.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pressed+the+button%2Cpushed+the+button&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpressed%20the%20button%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpushed%20the%20button%3B%2Cc0) But don't over-think this one - both versions are fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is exactly what my recollections told me. Glad to have them confirmed.

Comment: They are, afterall, called “ push buttons” not “press buttons”:  https://www.amazon.com/Pushbutton-Switches/b?ie=UTF8&node=5739464011

Comment: I feel like the message on telephone menus is always Press, never Push. I don't know how to support this feeling, though. I tried ngrams but had no luck. So I just went to Google and typed "For English p." Google offered various auto-completes with "press," but none with "push." It seems that somehow the advice "For English Push One" would make you think "one what?" while "For English Press One" more obviously means "press the one key."

Comment: “Press” always seems a little more formal than push.  Probably because *push* sounds “so brutish” and “press” more genteel.

Comment: Watch it!!  You're pushing some people's buttons just discussing this!

Comment: (And let's not forget that *press* is failing these days!)

Comment: Despite the overall preference for ***press***, the metaphoric version is nearly always [*He certainly knows **how to push my buttons***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+to+push+my+buttons%2Chow+to+press+my+buttons&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chow%20to%20push%20my%20buttons%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20to%20press%20my%20buttons%3B%2Cc0) (how to get me to react predictably, whether positively or negatively).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either option is fine. In this case, the words are synonymous. You are thinking of the wrong definition of the word *push*; the right one here is:

> [with obj.] press (a part of a machine or other device):
>   *he pushed the button for the twentieth floor.*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/push)</sub>

Comment: There are cases where one is more idiomatic than the other, but there aren't any real "rules" as to how one would decide this.  For instance, though "pushed" is probably most idiomatic in your quote above, it would be most idiomatic (in the US) for someone stepping into an elevator to say "Please press three for me."

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the word "press" generally implies exerting no force, because the object of the verb won't require any. Consider the buttons on a keyboard, or in an elevator - it doesn't take any strength to activate them.

As FumbleFingers mentions, native speakers use both words interchangeably when referring to buttons. In such cases we don't think of "push" as implying the need for force either.

There *is* a small preference for "push" if the button actually does require some slight force; for example, if it has a spring mechanism. One is also more likely to say "push" with toggle buttons (which have 'in' and 'out' states), because the button physically moves and remains depressed.

Comment: I do not strictly understand "force" as "great force", such as is required to push open a door. Rather, it is the application of physical effect on something. 
As for a toggle button, would one not rather use "switch" if it flicks between two states, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: "Switch" is usually for devices that move on a hinge (or sometimes twist, like on a lamp) - and we don't call them buttons, we call them switches. The "toggle buttons" I had in mind actually push *into* the material they're built on, and remain that way with some kind of spring or latch mechanism.

Comment: I see what construction you are referring to. In that case, pushing this sort of button seems suiting since it is actually "pushing down" that button... Thanks for the addition!

Comment: "Press" implies no force? Tell that to people who do ["bench presses"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bench_press). (On second thought, that might not be such a good idea.)

Comment: Cute joke, but we all know that's a completely different idiom for the word "press" than the OP was asking about ;)

Answer (score 0):

Press is an action where you apply force as if you are squeezing the object against something on the opposite side of the force.
Push is an action where you apply force with the intention to make the object move. So, both are sometime interchangable depending on the intention of the speaker.